# Java Cannot Load Main Class Without Adding .java

Tags: java, command-line

I'm trying to run a Java class file which I've compiled, but it keeps telling me that it cannot find or load the main class.

I have a directory which looks like this:
[image: Directory]

My goal is to run the RandomWord.java file, which takes in a file input and relies on the algs4.jar file found in the .lift sub-directory.
From what I've seen, to compile, I need to run the following (assuming I'm cd'ed into the hello directory):
$ javac -cp .lift/algs4.jar RandomWord.java
This should create my RandomWord.class file.
Now, to run it with a txt file, for example with coin.txt, I believe I should be running the following:
$ java -cp .lift/algs4.jar RandomWord < coin.txt
However, this results in an error stating: Error: Could not find or load main class RandomWord.

I've done a ton of experimenting with this but I have no idea what's going on, but I've found that running the following works:
$ java -cp .lift/algs4.jar RandomWord.java < coin.txt
However, I believe when a .class file is created, I shouldn't be writing .java in my command line, so I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows:

```
$ java -cp ".lift/algs4.jar;." RandomWord < coin.txt
```

Linux/Mac

```
$ java -cp ".lift/algs4.jar:." RandomWord < coin.txt
```

Current dir must be added to classpath to allow java to find classes there.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It worked. Could I possibly what the semicolon and dot at the end of the quotation represent? Is it just to add the current directory into the classpath as well?

Comment: Semicolon is a path separator in windows, Colon is used on unix systems. dot means the current directory on both (win/nix)

Comment: I see, thank you so much!! I understand why it didn't work now. I'm assuming the reason my other files which did not need the algs4.jar file worked was because I did not pass in anything to the classpath so it defaulted to the current dir, but since I wanted to specify the classpath in this case I had to do it for every single dir?

Comment: Yes, I think so.